# Help Evaluating Infinite Definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am reading a publication and trying to follow all of the derivations, but I am having trouble evaluating the following integral which they say has a solution!

```
Integrate[(1/2 (phiM + x + y)^2 + 
phiM^3/24 (3 phiM^2 + 12 phiM*x + 12 x^2)) (((phiM + x + y)^2 + 
 phiM^2 (3/4 phiM^2 + x^2 + 2 x*phiM + y*phiM + 2 x*y))/((phiM + 
    x + y)^2 + (1/4 phiM^2) (phiM + 2 x)^2)^3 - 
1/((phiM + x + 
    y)^2 + (1/12 phiM^2) (phiM^2 + 4 x*phiM + 4 y*phiM + 
     12 x*y))^2), {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

Sorry I know it looks like a mess, but the integral is integrated over y from 0 to Infinity and x, phiM are both constants of integration. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the integral in a more simpler view:

[image]

Comment: Adding the equation in the math form might help.

Comment: @anderstood ok done!

Comment: Any assumptions on `x`, `phiM`? Real? Positive?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've tried those assumptions in the integration but it did not help :(

Comment: Who is this they?

Comment: @Feyre The authors of the publication

Comment: I believe you can just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus here to get a closed form, i.e. substitute the endpoints into the anti-derivate. Numerically (w.r.t. x and phi), it seems to be correct.

Comment: @ChipHurst Is there a way to ask Mathematica to find the anti-derivative?

Comment: @user1886681 just replace `{y, 0, Infinity}` with `y`.

Comment: @ChipHurst I think its the Infinity limit that's giving issues...because after finding the anti-derivative and applying the limit Limit[...,{y0->Infinity}] Mathematica hangs

Comment: @user1886681 I was able to evaluate the whole thing. I believe I used the option `Assumptions -> x > 0 && phiM > 0` inside `Limit`.

Comment: I am surprised that this makes trouble as this is just integrals of the form $y^n/(a y^2+by+c)^3$, with $n=0,1,2,3,4$, etc. and the last part being even easier....but I agree: it is often better to skip the limits and check on that later manually.

Comment: @ChipHurst Yeah this works, for `y=0` too, do you want to answer the question or close it, since it turns out to be relatively basic.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully integrated it with the assumptions as follows:

```
    int=Integrate[(1/2 (phiM + x + y)^2 + 
    phiM^3/24 (3 phiM^2 + 12 phiM*x + 12 x^2)) (((phiM + x + y)^2 + 
       phiM^2 (3/4 phiM^2 + x^2 + 2 x*phiM + y*phiM + 
          2 x*y))/((phiM + x + 
           y)^2 + (1/4 phiM^2) (phiM + 2 x)^2)^3 - 
    1/((phiM + x + y)^2 + (1/12 phiM^2) (phiM^2 + 4 x*phiM + 
           4 y*phiM + 12 x*y))^2), {y, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {phiM > 0, x > 0}]
```

using Mma11, Win7. The result is here but it is huge. Here is an image of a verysmall part of it to make you believe:
[image]
Nevertheless, one can operate with it. For example,

```
Plot3D[int, {x, 0, 10}, {phiM, 0, 10}]
```

gives

[image]

Have fun!